# Extract first X Numbers from Text Field using Regex

Tags: r

I have strings that looks like this.

```
x <- c("P2134.asfsafasfs","P0983.safdasfhdskjaf","8723.safhakjlfds")
```

I need to end up with:

```
"2134", "0983", and "8723"
```

Essentially, I need to extract the first four characters that are numbers from each element. Some begin with a letter (disallowing me from using a simple substring() function).

I guess technically, I could do something like:

```
x <- gsub("^P","",x)
x <- substr(x,1,4)
```

But I want to know how I would do this with regex!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `gsub` too.

```
> sub('.?([0-9]{4}).*', '\\1', x)
[1] "2134" "0983" "8723"
>
```

I used `sub` instead of `gsub` to assure I only got the first match.  `.?` says any single character and its optional (similar to just `.` but then it wouldn't match the case without the leading `P`).  The `()` signify a group that I reference in the replacement `'\\1'`.  If there were multiple sets of `()` I could reference them too with `'\\2'`.  Inside the group, and you had the syntax correct, I want only numbers and I want exactly 4 of them.  The final piece says zero or more trailing characters of any type.

Your syntax was working, but you were replacing something with itself so you wind up with the same output.

Comment: You know, I was fiddling with something like sub('[0-9]{4}','\\1'). Would you mind explaining the code?

Comment: That's how I feel about regex in general - dangerous! It's very difficult to rely on something that "feels" so unreadable.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [str_match](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/stringr/docs/str_match) from the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
print(c(str_match(x, "\\d\\d\\d\\d")))
# [1] "2134" "0983" "8723"
```

Comment: +1 simple, straight forward. Thoughts on how to do this with base R?

Comment: I'm a fan of the `stringr` functions just because they maintain consistent syntax.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen: Justin's answer is the most straightforward way to do it with base R.

Answer (score 1):

#### This will get you the first four digits of a string, regardless of where in the string they appear.

```
mapply(function(x, m) paste0(x[m], collapse=""), 
        strsplit(x, ""),
        lapply(gregexpr("\\d", x), "[", 1:4))
```

#### Breaking it down into pieces:

What's going on in the above line is as follows:

```
# this will get you a list of matches of digits, and their location in each x
matches <- gregexpr("\\d", x)

# this gets you each individual digit
matches <- lapply(matches, "[", 1:4)

# individual characters of x
splits <- strsplit(x, "")

# get the appropriate string
mapply(function(x, m) paste0(x[m], collapse=""), splits, matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another group capturing approach that doesn't assume 4 numbers.

```
x <- c("P2134.asfsafasfs","P0983.safdasfhdskjaf","8723.safhakjlfds") 

gsub("(^[^0-9]*)(\\d+)([^0-9].*)", "\\2", x)

## [1] "2134" "0983" "8723"
```